# How to find sin and cos of 0, pi/2, pi without calculator

Tags: trigonometry

In my notes it shows how to calculate by using the unit circle. But I do not know why the value of sin is the y coordinate and the value of cos is the x coordinate.

Comment: These values are constants you can easily remember. What do you really want to know?

Comment: "But I do not know why the value of sin is the y coordinate and the value of cos is the x coordinate." Often this is the definition.

Comment: This will be helpful https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQtwIwAGoVChMImpWg65qDxwIVTsSOCh0jZgB6&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DcIVpemcoAlY&ei=BEi6VZqDJM6IuwSjzIHQBw&usg=AFQjCNFrW3I8vwJFk5IAX-U-nVmI4S7Z2Q&sig2=GXZkZ0luVsb0qEn-pyh6lw

Comment: If $x$ is the adjacent side of the reference triangle, and the hypotenuse is $1$ (because the unit circle has a radius of $1$), then $$x = \frac{x}{1} = \frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \cos\theta$$

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your difficulty is, so I'll use the geometrical definition to get the requested values. This definition means that when going a distance of $\theta$ counter-clockwise along the unit circle starting at $(1,0)$, the coordinates of the point on the circle are $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.

Note that $0$ corresponds to the point $(1,0)$ on the unit circle, i.e.
$$\sin(0) = 0, \cos(0) = 1$$
$\frac\pi2$ represents a quarter of a circle ($90^\circ$) wich corresponds to $(0,1)$ on the unit circle, i.e.
$$\sin(\frac\pi2) = 1, \cos(\frac\pi2) = 0$$
Finally, $\pi$ corresponds to half a circle ($180^\circ$) wich corresponds to $(-1,0)$. This means
$$\sin(\pi) = 0, \cos(\pi) = -1$$

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to remember the graph of $\cos(x)$

[[image: enter image description here[1]